# How to avoid WebStorm mark comments in coverage of Jest test?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, webstorm

I'm doing the test for my application and running them with the `coverage` option of Jest, but every time I run one, the comments of my functions are marked like the lines are not covered, there is a way of avoiding this? Here is my Jest config and also a screenshot of the problem:

alias.js

```
// Configuración de rutas de directorios y archivos
const appPaths = require('./paths');

// Different formats for each thing:
module.exports = {
  jest: {
    '^@assets(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/assets$1',
    '^@components(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components$1',
    '^@modReducers(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/modules$1',
    '^@constants(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/shared/constants$1',
    '^@helpers(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^@services(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/services$1',
    '^@screens(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/screens$1'
  }
};
```

jest.config.js

```
const path = require('path'),
  aliasConfig = require("../alias");

module.exports = {
  collectCoverage: true,
  moduleNameMapper: aliasConfig.jest,
  rootDir: path.join(process.cwd(), ''),
  verbose: true
};
```

And this is the problem that I'm facing:
[image: Jest test over a function]

Comment: haven't faced such issues. Sample project that can be used to reproduce it would be appreciated